# Null handling in Informatica IDQ profile's (Big data Developer/BDM)

Tags: informatica-powercenter

i'm using Informatica BDM tool (10.2.2) for data quality purpose. In process of creating a profile on 1 column, I'm facing an issue.

issue:
column having 100 records of which 50 are valid records,25 are invalid and 25 are null records. when I create a rule on the column and add that rule in the profile, i'm getting 50 as valid and 50 as invalid.
where are nulls are also showing as invalid.

Code: IIF(INSTR(col,'*',1,1)||INSTR(col,'*',1,2)='T'||'R', 'Valid', 'Invalid')

Note: I want only 2 results to be seen in the profile (Valid/Invalid).

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks.